# wc_get_products how to get empty description products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try to get list of empty description products but the following code isn't working, please help me.

```
class UpdateEmptyDescriptionProducts {

    public function handle_custom_query( $query, $query_vars ) {
        $metaQueries = [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [
                'key'       => 'description',
                'value'     => '',
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ],
            [
                'key'       => 'description',
                'value'     => 'null',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ],
        ];
        $query['meta_query'][] = $metaQueries;
        return $query;
    }

    public function main(){

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', [$this, 'handle_custom_query'], 11, 2 );

        $emptyDescriptionWcProducts = wc_get_products([
            'orderby' => 'modified',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'limit' => 1
        ]);

        foreach ($emptyDescriptionWcProducts as $wcProduct) {
            var_dump($wcProduct);
            var_dump($wcProduct->get_id());
            var_dump($wcProduct->get_description());
        }
    }

}
```

The result shows that the product description is not empty:

[Click here to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8B2I.png)

Comment: Have your tried `$metaQueries = [
 [
  'key'      => 'description',
  'value'    => ['', 'null']
  'relation' => 'OR',
 ]
];`

Comment: The result is empty.

Comment: Please add results in post, not as a link. That way we can read right away and when source linked disappears code will still be here.